Bug of 'eventlet' for 'celery' on Windows 10
my env:

Windows 10, Celery 5.3.6, eventlet 0.36.1

question:

I meet the same question on celery-issues. And I try celery -A [task] worker -l info -P eventlet, but I even can not connect redis. The output as follow:
enter image description here

Why this bug happend? how to fix it?
Thanks for everyone's attention!

Just so you know, Celery is not supported on Windows.

Firstly, please don't use images here if they only contain text. Copy'n'paste the text instead. Then, there's too much handwaving here, not enough concrete info. What did you do? What happened? Those are important, not just what you intended to achieve and how you interpret the results. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].
